# Deciphering a likelihood expression

Tags: probability, likelihood

I came across an isolated likelihood expression in a paper that is presented as a function of other probabilities. The terms within the parentheses are defined, but I could not find definitions for the *α* and *x* operators used. How can I make sense of this expression? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: it depends on the context! If you want an answer, you should paste the relevant parts of the paper here, or at least provide the reference/link to the paper

Comment: Thank you for your input, I have added the relevant sections.

Answer (score 1):

If symbols are not defined, then that is pretty much the end of the story. All we can do is guess.

The $\alpha$ could be a weird rendition of a $\propto$, that is, "proportional to" or "ignoring a constant". That trick is used a lot in maximum likelihood, so that would make sense.

The $x$ may be a weird rendition of $\times$, i.e. explicitly indicating a multiplication, but I am less convinced about that one.

Comment: The proportionality is a good suggestion, although I share your doubt about the x. It would be dreadfully inconsistent if was used a multiplication operator. I agree however that it is generally unclear.

Comment: I agree that the $\alpha$ is intended as $\propto$ and I think you're right about the $x$ being $\times$ as well.